# How to use Entity in a Multilingual Agents

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I am having a problem with how to use the entity type correctly in multilingual Agents.
If I were to make an entity type in a language let's say in THAI and a route for that specific entity using the $session.params.(entitytype) = something but then if my agent is multilingual then when I go to the same entity type in another language let's say English all the entity in my default language does not show up on the English agent. Do I just add all the English matching words to the Thai entity type? Or is it better the build 1 agent for each language? Or do I route to the samepage using a new $session.params.(entitytype) = english something and so one for each lang

[Defult Thai Agent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qy3C5.png)

[Same Agent but English](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaaKB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Switching agents Is one approach, but if you want to use multilingual entities, yes, you should add all the matching words to the Thai entity type. For dialog flow, each language entity is separated from the in my experience, also you need to add both languages at the agent. some simpler entities can be handled by the agent that way.

Here is more info about it: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/agents-multilingual

Answer (score 0):

Entity entries are [language-specific data](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/agent-multilingual#lang-specific).

First, you need to add entity entries to the [entity type](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/entity) for each language. Then you can create multiple [routes](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/handler#route) with [conditions](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/condition) like `$session.params.<entity_type_name> = "<some_text_in_Thai>"` and `$session.params.<entity_type_name> = "<some_text_in_English>"`.